# How to get values from datebase in free version of Soap UI?

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

**I have only a free version of Soap Ui available.**
I am struggling with substitution account for different parameters in automatic webservice tests. At the moment it generates values via random values.

I would like to use the values of downloading from the database, if it is trivial in the pro version, unfortunately the free version is stripped down and I'm not sure about the use of **groovy script**.

@Edit - suggestion in comment

I tried configure via `JDBC Request`, but i dont have any idea about syntax in `connection string:` field

[image]

Comment: Show your jdbc step configuration.

Comment: I can't configure a DB connection in free version for JDBC Request.

Comment: Have you gone thru documentation? what data base are you trying to connect? What version of soapui are you using?

Comment: I believe you must be receiving some error. Can you share error you get when you execute the query with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC configuration panel in the Pro version of soapUI is virtually identical to your screen shot, and the connection string is just a standard JDBC connection string, which you already have. If you need to substitute properties in the string, try:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SID?user=${#Project#databaseUsername}&password=${#Project#databasePassword}`

In this case, `databaseUsername` and `databasePassword` are project level properties. See https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html for more about the syntax.

And, the JDBC response will be an XML payload that looks like:

```
<Results>
   <ResultSet fetchSize="0">
      <Row rowNumber="1">
         <TABLE.COLUMN>41</TABLE.COLUMN>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="2">
         <TABLE.COLUMN>42</TABLE.COLUMN>
      </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

You'll be able to extract values from it using XPath like:

```
${jdbcTestStep#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/TABLE.COLUMN[1]}
```

Comment: Correct advice. work perfect. Thank you i will back to the work :)